# Static class / constant field hierarchy - can it be done?

Tags: java, oop, static, hierarchy

What I'm trying to achieve is a nice abstraction for my database tables. The result I'm looking for is to be able to do this:

```
System.out.println(Table.Appointment);    // prints the name of the table 
System.out.println(Table.Appointment.ID); // prints the name of the column
```

Here is what I've come close with, but fields seem to take priority over static inner classes.

```
public class Table {

    // attempt to allow 'Table.Appointment' to resolve to a String
    public static final Table Appointment = new Table("Appointment");

    // attempt to give access to column names within the table,
    // these class names should be the same as its name field above.
    public static final class Appointment{
        public static final String ID = "AppointmentId";
    };

    private String name; 
    private Table(String name){ this.name = name; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Can this actually be achieved?

Comment: so rename your instance variables - don't capitalize them for this reason among others.

Comment: you want enums for your task, bit why not using jpa metamodel?

Comment: @Jake223 I'm always an enforcer of naming conventions but for this task I would like to have them be consistent with the static class names.

Comment: @guido I had a version of this where I tried to use enums but didn't get very far. I'll look up the jpa metamodel now.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "fields seem to take priority over static inner classes"? And what does your Appointment class do? It does not seem to be used at all.

Comment: if you use the conventions then you won't run into this problem though...

Comment: @Thilo, for example the second `println` statement will fail: "cannot find variable ID at location variable Appointment of type db.Table". So it tries to find ID in the Table field rather than as a static field in the static inner class. Which makes sense.

Comment: If that is the question, I agree with @Jake223: Just give different things different names.

Comment: @Jake223 What are you suggesting then? Because if I follow naming conventions it breaks the consistency of the hierarchy as indicated in the two `println` statement.

Comment: @pst Yeah took a long time trying to figure out a good title, not so easy for this particular question.

Comment: @paranoid-android why would you want to have two different things of the exact same name? it just seems like it makes for hard-to-read code to me.

Comment: @Jake223 It's a tradeoff, because the database code would be very easy to read even though the Table class (which serves as an abstraction for the database code) will not be as easy to read.

Comment: Why is the consistency of the hierarchy in the two statements more important than consistency with how the rest of the world reads Java code? Especially when that hierarchy does not really map to Java's hierarchy. Inner classes are just namespaces, define no relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I strongly discourage what you are doing, simply because it makes your application too solid, this works (**Edited** to avoid cyclic references.) :

```
public final class Table {

    // ===== DECLARE YOUR INSTANCES HERE =====

    static public final AppointmentTable Appointment = new AppointmentTable();
    // static public final FooTable Foo = new FooTable();

    // =======================================

    static private abstract class TableImpl {
        public abstract String getTableName();
        public String toString() { return getTableName(); }
    }

    // ==== DECLARE YOUR DEFINITIONS BELOW ====

    static public class AppointmentTable extends TableImpl {
        public final String ID = "appointmentId";
        // public final <type> <columnName> = <dbFieldName>;

        public String getTableName() { return "appointment"; }
        private AppointmentTable() {}
    }

    // static public class FooTable extends TableImpl { ... }

}
```

This is as close as you can get from what you want. Note that users won't actually see this design, only programmers will... so who cares?

Also, having access to `Table.AppointmentTable` is normal. This is how you can access `Table.Appointment.ID`. But you can't create an instance of it neither extend it, and it is all good.

** **Edit** **

Why this limitation? Because you can't just use a type and treat it as a value. A type defines the container, not the content. And as much as you can't `System.out.println(int);` because `int` is a token (or a type, or a container), you cannot treat a class name as a value that you can echo. Among other things, this is why you have `Table.AppointmentTable.class.getSimpleName()` (or `.getName()`).

You can only work with values. A class definition is *not* a value, it's a definition of a container *for* a value. The variable of that class definition hold the content of that container, from which you can echo or manipulate.

The same thing goes with unassigned variables. If you try :

```
int foo;
System.out.println(foo);
```

the compiler will whine about `foo` not being initialized. This is because declaring a variable does not assign any content to it (you declare a container of type `int` named `foo`), does not make it hold any content unless you assign something (contents) to it.

Comment: This is interesting, however would result in calls like this: `Table.AppointmentTable.ID` and `Table.Appointment`. It's close as well, but I'm still curious to know if there's a solution that is perfectly consistent.

Comment: I edited my example to remove cyclic table references and making everything final. I don't think you'll be able to achieve something closer to what you expect. And I did add some clarifications. If you need more explanations, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like

```
Table appointment = new Table("appointment" // table name
                            , "appointmentId"  // id column name);

System.out.println(appointment.getTableName());    
System.out.println(appointment.getIdColumnName());
```

If you want to push things done to compile-time, you could use subclasses.

```
class Appointment extends Table{
    Appointment(){  super("appointment", "appointmentId"); }
}
```

Comment: This defeats the whole point of the question. It's very easy to just use generic names with default get methods.